# WPF DataGrid Binding to CurrentItem or SelectedItem?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

If I have a `DataGrid` in my `View` and a `Property` in my `ViewModel` that represents currently active `DataGridRow` (e.g. focused item or clicked item) should I bind my Property to `SelectedItem` or `CurrentItem`. Say I chose to bind it to `SelectedItem`, then What's `CurrentItem` for? should I bind another Property to `CurrentItem`?

Comment: What is CurrentItem & SelectedItem here?

Comment: @SaiKalyanKumarAkshinthala He is referring to the properties DataGrid.CurrentItem and DataGrid.SelectedItem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at this: [DataGrid CurrentItem != SelectedItem after reentry with tab-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297665/datagrid-currentitem-selecteditem-after-reentry-with-tab-button)

> First of all a row is selected by the user which makes the datagrid show that row in the selected way (SelectedItem and also CurrentItem contain the selected object). Then the focus is given to another control. In this status - the selection is still shown - SelectedItem is still there while CurrentItem is null!

Good article: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/selection/selecteditem-currentitem.html

Comment: This is terrible, not your answer, but Microsoft's design. Does the current day cease to be when I look at my watch. The only time current-anything should be null is at the start when it has yet to be assigned.